# Ragged arange in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an arbitrarily nested ragged tensor `x` I need to perform masking on. Something like:

```py
x = tf.ragged.constant([
    [[12, 9], [5]],
    [[10], [6, 8], [42]],
])
```

The easiest way for me to mask will be by index of an element along the 1st axis. Is there a way to get a ragged `arange` with the same row lengths/splits like:

```py
x = tf.ragged.constant([
    [[0, 1], [2]],
    [[0], [1, 2], [3]],
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by merging the n-d tensor up to rank2, calculating a ragged range over that, and then essentially reshaping it from the original nested row lengths:

```py
x = tf.ragged.constant([
    [[12, 9], [5]],
    [[10], [6, 8], [42]],
])

x_2d = x.merge_dims(inner_axis=-1, outer_axis=1)
arange_2d = tf.ragged.range(x_2d.row_lengths())
arange_nd = tf.RaggedTensor.from_nested_row_lengths(
    arange_2d.flat_values,
    x.nested_row_lengths(),
)

>>> arange_nd
<tf.RaggedTensor [[[0, 1], [2]], [[0], [1, 2], [3]]]>
```

See [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44164) for an alternative solution from one of the Tensorflow maintainers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.ragged.constant([
    [[12, 9], [5]],
    [[10], [6, 8], [42]],
])

starts = tf.gather(x.nested_row_splits[1], x.nested_row_splits[0])[1:-1]
starts = tf.cast(starts, tf.int32)
len = tf.shape(x.flat_values)[0]
starts = tf.scatter_nd(starts[:,tf.newaxis], starts, [len])
starts = tf.scan(lambda a, x: a + x, starts)
output = tf.range(len) - starts
x = tf.RaggedTensor.from_nested_row_splits(output, x.nested_row_splits)

print(x)
```